# "HandshakeCompleteNotify" thread causes program to stall

Tags: java, multithreading, freeze

So, I'm running into a strange issue and I'm really stuck.  I have a long winded process (loads 10 million + records into salesforce).  When I run this process everything goes well until the end.

At the end of this process, I wait for confirmation back from salesforce that all records have loaded successfully.

Sometimes (not always but most of the time), the program just seems to stall.  If I pause the debugger, it doesn't pull up any code lines and I can't use the "step" functions.  While its stalling, a thread flashes faster than I can read what it says.  I managed to capture it by screen-shooting my desktop as fast as I could.

[image]

Any advice on how to trouble shoot this?  Insight to why this might be happening?  I'm a bit out of my comfort zone with this one.

### Update

So it turns out, after a very long time it finally does return as expected.  It appears that the thread is doing some sort of work and but maybe isn't getting a fair share of the resources?  Still have no idea why it's happening.  Maybe it has something to do with a **thread.sleep()** call I'm making in a loop?

This is basically the code in question.  It came from [this resource put out by salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/).

```
/**
 * Wait for a job to complete by polling the Bulk API.
 * 
 * @param connection
 *            BulkConnection used to check results.
 * @param job
 *            The job awaiting completion.
 * @param batchInfoList
 *            List of batches for this job.
 * @throws AsyncApiException
 */
private void awaitCompletion(BulkConnection connection, JobInfo job,
      List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList)
        throws AsyncApiException {
    long sleepTime = 0L;
    Set<String> incomplete = new HashSet<String>();
    for (BatchInfo bi : batchInfoList) {
        incomplete.add(bi.getId());
    }
    while (!incomplete.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Awaiting results..." + incomplete.size());
        sleepTime = 10000L;
        BatchInfo[] statusList =
          connection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
        for (BatchInfo b : statusList) {
            if (b.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed
              || b.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) {
                if (incomplete.remove(b.getId())) {
                    System.out.println("BATCH STATUS:\n" + b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding sleep calls into code doesn't fix anything. It just masks bugs, probably temporarily.

Comment: @EJP I didn't add a sleep call to "fix" anything.  There is a sleep call used in a function that pools the server to see if the import is complete.  In other words... Is my upload done? no... Ok, sleep for 10 seconds.  I didn't personally write this code. I'll add the link to the resource I got it from in the question